# Parse formatted string into an array

Tags: java

I am using an InputSteam that receives strings in this format.

[[1,3,4],[43,6,3],[4,2,5]]

How would I parse that into a usable java array?

Comment: Easiest would be to use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson): `new ObjectMapper().readValue("[[1,3,4],[43,6,3],[4,2,5]]", int[][].class)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to parse that text without use of 3rd-party library.

```
public static int[][] parse(String text) {
    if (! text.startsWith("[[") || ! text.endsWith("]]"))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid text: " + text);
    String[] subTexts = text.substring(2, text.length() - 2).split("\\],\\[");
    int[][] result = new int[subTexts.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < subTexts.length; i++) {
        String[] valueTexts = subTexts[i].split(",");
        result[i] = new int[valueTexts.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < valueTexts.length; j++)
            result[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(valueTexts[j]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(parse("[[1,3,4],[43,6,3],[4,2,5]]")));
```

*Output*

```
[[1, 3, 4], [43, 6, 3], [4, 2, 5]]
```

Comment: impressive!+1, I was thinking that whether I could use regex, however it does the job well!

Comment: @snr Technically, it is using regex, since that is what `split()` uses.

Comment: yes, that's right, really well done, if I had a chance to vote more than one, I would, no doubt!

Comment: `split()` doesn't always use regex. Unless you mean the specification.

Comment: @shmosel The *implementation* may (or may not) have *optimization* to bypass regex engine for simple `regex` (name of parameter) values, but you're always giving a **regex pattern** as the parameter, hence "split is using regex". Whether the method uses the regex engine or not is besides the point.

Comment: It's besides *your* point perhaps, bit it wasn't fully clear what that was :)

Comment: @shmosel My original point was that snr was "thinking of using regex, but `split` works as well" *(paraphrased)*, but since `split` takes a regex argument, using `split` means you're using regex (regex pattern = using regex). I used the word "technically", because I understood his comment to mean "use regex = use `Pattern` class", but *technically*, direct use of `Pattern` is not the only way to use regex, e.g. there is also `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt (somewhat verbose, though). The program created the `int[][]` in each case with following three input strings - when tried individually:

```
"[[1,3,4],[43,6,3],[4,2,5]]"
"[[]]"
"[[],[1,2,3],[0]]"
```

The program code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class ArrayParsing {
    private final static String input = "[[1,3,4],[43,6,3],[4,2,5]]";
    private final static String open = "[";
    private final static String open2 = "[[";
    private final static String close = "]";
    private final static String close2 = "]]";
    private final static List<int []> outerContent = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String content = "";
        String token = "";
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            token = input.substring(i, i+1);
            if (token.equals(open) || token.equals(open2)) {
                content = "";
                flag = false;
            }
            else if (token.equals(close) && !flag) {
                buildArray(content);
                flag = true;
            }
            else {
                content = content.concat(token);
            }
        }
        int [][] result = outerContent.toArray(new int[outerContent.size()][]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
    }
    private static void buildArray(String in) {
        int [] intArray = new int[0];   
        if (in.trim().length() > 0) {
            String [] elements = in.split(",");
            intArray = Arrays.stream(elements)
                             .mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
                             .toArray();
        }
        outerContent.add(intArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: With `token = input.substring(i, i+1)`, i.e. exactly 1 character long, how would you ever expect `token.equals(open2)` to be true? --- Doing `content = content.concat(token)` is a loop is bad for performance. Use a `StringBuilder`. --- `s -> Integer.parseInt(s)` can be a method reference, i.e. `Integer::parseInt`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The code is an example - its not a solution as it is. A real application would define what the requirements are - a little more in detail. What are the validation requirements? How the program need to behave if an empty string is passed or when there are no commas between two arrays? What is the behavior and outcome when there is a non-integer or alphabetic character? These have to be taken (and more) into consideration when one builds an application. _Continued in the next comment..._

Comment: Continues from previous comment: As I wrote the code there were quite a few ideas and approaches as I considered - how one goes about solving (I haven't looked at the already posted solutions). As I mentioned, its a way one can figure a solution and there are different approaches (but you know that already). Finally, the points you had observed are good and are valid.